# PHP Cron Jobs Performance And Curl

Tags: php, performance, cron

Running PHP 5.3, mysql and ubuntu I have a cron job which needs to be ran every 30 seconds.

The cronjob is calling a cURL script which downloads some data and stores it the database, the average request time is 7 seconds which is causing issues when I try to access the website fro a browser.

This project is still in dev but at present this would mean delays to visitors approximately 20% of the time.

What are the ways around this problem.

My suggestions:

- look into processes and forking with apache (not sysadmin guy and don't really know what I am doing)
- moving the PHP script to another virtual host on the server and calling it from cron (preferred, not sure if it is hacky, or bad practice)
- writing a small program in C++ or java and calling it from a cron (doable)
- redesigning and rewriting in java with a more scalable architecture (don't want to do this and surely if so many huge sites run PHP I shouldn't need to)

Thanks in advance to anyone who offers there help,

Comment: _'Every 30 seconds'_ why? Can you outline the reason behind the 30sec process? Are you trying to mimic real-time? On a side note do you mean 7sec execution time or request time?

Comment: Why would a cron job be causing issues when you access the site?  What about the functions in the cron job is hindering your server from serving the web page files as normal?

Comment: @SajanParikh - The functions in the script are just loading curl and downloading data from a website.  I don't know why it is hindering the server but it seems that whenever the cron is running the response from the server is slow.

Comment: Apache will open need php threads as required & pools a few extra. So having a single call on a cron will be fine, you have another issue. Btw php fork will not work through apache it will only work through php cli

Comment: A cron job for every seconds can be overkill. Instead, the latest data can be fetched in real time and directly displayed in the site, instead of storing it in the database.